# if statement not executed appropriately

Tags: python

```
labs = 10.8
superquiz = 15.0
test = 51.0
project = 49.5
exam = 53.5

def course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam):
    """Return the total as an unrounded floating-point value"""
    mark2 = labs * 7/100 + superquiz * 14/100 + test * 10/100 + project * 30/100 + exam * 39/100
    return mark2
print (labs * 7/100 + superquiz * 14/100 + test * 10/100 + project * 30/100 + exam * 39/100)



course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam)
if course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam) >= 50/100:
    print("Course total pass: " + "yes" + " "+ "("+'{0:.2%}'.format(course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam) / 100) + ")")
else:
    print("Course total pass: " + "no" + " " + "("+'{0:.2%}'.format(course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam) / 100) +")")
```

The `course_total` is less than 50% but how come this `else` clause is not executed accordingly?
It is supposed to go to `else` clause and the Course total pass should be `"no"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition to this:

```
if course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam) >= 50.0:
```

```
50/100 = .5 #which is less than

course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam) #which gives 43.6709
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the result from course_total is 43.67 and you are checking if it's bigger than 50/100 (0.5). 
This should just be 50, because your function returns a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Your result values `43.666` and you test it again `0.5`, you see the difference, Also you're computing it 4 times, just save it in a variable to compute it once

```
total = course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam) / 100
print(total)  # 0.43670999999999993
if total >= 50 / 100:
    print("Course total pass: " + "yes" + " " + "(" + '{0:.2%}'.format(total) + ")")
else:
    print("Course total pass: " + "no" + " " + "(" + '{0:.2%}'.format(total) + ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking it aginst **50/100** in your IF clause. Compare it against just 50.0

Also remove the redundant method call above your if statement, that is not needed.

```
course_total(labs, superquiz, test, project, exam)
```

Remove this line.